# Descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'Series' (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

So, I have the following DataFrame:

[image]

I would like to convert those datetime values to date, so I tried:

```
df['Notification Date']= datetime.date(df['Notification Date'])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: assuming your column `df['Notification Date']` already is of type datetime, you might want `df['Notification Date'] = df['Notification Date'].dt.date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `pd.to_datetime` for pandas series:

```
df['Notification Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Notification Date'])
```

Comment: Not all  column values are datetime. Some values are strings. How could I convert only the datetime values?

Comment: @Incognito You should list that in your sample data. On the other note, column name `Notification Date` suggests that the data should be date time. Why do you want string there?

Comment: Some cells have the value "Never"

Comment: Pass `errors='coerce'` which converts `Never` into `pd.NaT` timestamp. You can also pass `errors='ignore'` to `pd.to_datetime` instead to keep the string.

Comment: OK. For some reason, this code outputs the very same values (datetime, not date). Is there something else I should do?

Comment: Look at MrFuppes' comment.

Comment: OK. The output is "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values". It seems the string cells are the problem. How could I solve this?

Comment: Like this: df['Notification Date'] = df['Notification Date'].dt.date(errors = 'coerce') ? The same error message shows up.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['Notification Date'], errors='coerce').dt.date`.